# Is it possible to export reports from Jama Connect with baseline signatures

Tags: rest, velocity, requirements-management

I am working for a Medical Device company where we are using **Jama Connect** for Requirement Management.

To be compliant we have to externally submit information located in Jama for regulatory purposes.

One of the requirements is to have the information approved. **Approver / signature** is visible within Jama, but can not be exported without the use of a custom **Velocity** report (Jama report script language).

I was hoping that someone else has faced the same challenge and have a solution. There is also a REST API, but it does not seem that the info can be exported with that.

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but putting my suggestion in case someone comes across this. I haven't used the Jama API to extract data but have directly exported reports from the Jama database. Jama provides the DB schema which you can use to link the tables. I recently did a migration project for one client and as long as Jama provides the Database and files asse backup you should be able to extract the required information. Happy to share the solution if needed